# Dolphintabs menu is not working on joomla 1.6

Tags: javascript, menu, joomla, joomla1.6

i trying to use dolphin.js in joomla 1.6 template, buut i have a problem, the dolphin menu is not working, and i got an error message :

> document.getElementById(this.subcontainers[i])
>   is null [Break On This Error]
>   document.getElementById(this.subcontainers[i]).style.display="none"

Please help me out..
Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very like you have a JS conflict with Mootools. Try disabling the library [with something like this.](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/scripts/15748)